# Android networking does not work in emulator

Tags: android, networking

I am working on a basic client-server application to send messages between an android app (client) and a java server on the pc. The messages are being sent and received fine when I use the emulator but does not work when i try to use the app on my mobile. I connect my phone to a wifi network hosted by my laptop using connectify. I wonder whats preventing my phone from connecting... 
Here is the code :

SERVER

```
public class ServerMain {
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
  {
     String clientSentence;
     String capitalizedSentence;
     int sock = 1234; 
     ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(sock);

     while(true)
     {
        Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
        BufferedReader inFromClient =
           new BufferedReader(new            InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
        clientSentence = inFromClient.readLine();
        System.out.println("Received: " + clientSentence);
        if(clientSentence.equalsIgnoreCase("QUIT"))
            break;
     }
     welcomeSocket.close();

  }
}
```

CLIENT

```
public class Message extends Activity {
EditText et;
String msg1 = "";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etTest);
}
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
class GetMessages extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       final String msg = et.getText().toString();
         try{
            Socket clientSocket = new Socket("*myip*", 1234);
            DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            String sentence = msg;
            outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');

        } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
         return null;
    }

}    
  public void readWebpage(View view) { //The button on click calls this function (from xml)
   new GetMessages().execute();
   }
}
```

Comment: The title of this question says the opposite of the question itself. In the title it says that "networking does not work in emulator", but in the question body it says the opposite: "The messages are being sent and received fine when I use the emulator but does not work when i try to use the app on my mobile. "

Which is it?

If it works in the emulator but not on the real phone, I suggest you install https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm or something similar and try a ping to the server. First confirm that the network setup satisfies your expectations.